# I am trying to create a UIbarButtonItem whose width and height is equal to 70% of the height of the navigationbar?

Tags: swift

I am trying to write an extension fo UIBarButtonItem.  I would like to use auto layout so that the UIBarButtonItem's width and height is 70% of the height of the UINavigationBar.  When I implement this extension, i am getting the following auto layout errors:

```
import UIKit

extension UIBarButtonItem {

    static func menuButton(target: Any?, action: Selector, imageName: String, navigationBar: UINavigationBar) -> UIBarButtonItem{

        let button = UIButton.init(type: .system)
        let image = UIImage.init(named: imageName)
        button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)

        let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        menuButton.customView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        menuButton.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
        menuButton.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true

        return menuButton
    } 
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem.menuButton(target: self, action: #selector(editCells), imageName: "expand", navigationBar: navigationController!.navigationBar)

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

**Error message in console:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutDimension:0x600001be1180 "UIButton:0x7ff5d6d16b80.width"> and <NSLayoutDimension:0x600001be25c0 "UINavigationBar:0x7ff5d911a2f0.height"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom view for your navigationBar custom button and set properties for whatever you want like this:

```
func addRightButton() {

    let barButtonView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 180, height: 40)))
    barButtonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let navigationBarHeightWithRatio = (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 100) * 0.7
    let customBarButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 8, width: navigationBarHeightWithRatio, height: navigationBarHeightWithRatio))
    customBarButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "your_image_name"), for: .normal)
    customBarButton.setTitle("title", for: .normal)

    customBarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector("<your_action_function>"), for: .touchUpInside)

    barButtonView.addSubview(customBarButton)

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: barButtonView)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
}
```

**Note:**

- You can customize width different width, height values and x, y positions.

I hope it is works.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. When you say:

```
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem.menuButton(
    target: self, action: #selector(editCells), 
    imageName: "expand", 
    navigationBar: navigationController!.navigationBar)
```

... and the `menuButton` method runs, at that moment, you are trying to form a constraint relationship between the button and the navigation bar at a time when the button is not *in* the navigation bar. That, as the error message tells you, is illegal.

(I doubt that the goal you have outlined is possible *at all*, but that's another story. I'm just explaining the error message.)